# How to handle zoom and pan in d3 scaleOrdinal

Tags: d3.js

I have to create a custom stock chart with variable width x axis for each date.
I am using d3.scaleOrdinal for creating the x-axis

```
const xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["16-09-2022", "17-09-2022", "18-09-2022", "19-09-2022", "20-09-2022"])
    .range([0, 260, 500, 750, 900,1010]);
```

While zooming using geometric approach, the axis got scaled as a whole(i.e ticks, ticklabel, axis line) which I want to work like scaleLinear.

```
svg.select("#xaxis")
.attr("transform", `translate(${transform.x},${margin.top})scale(${transform.k}) `)
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve the desired result with d3 v7
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a continuous scale, like `scaleLinear`, otherwise it won't work because the ordinal scale cannot interpolate between values.

Think of it like having an array with indexes 0, 1, 2. There is no index 0.5 or 1.5, because ordinals are discrete whole values.